# Error running java application/applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, neural-network, sudoku

i am working on Neural network in java using the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/my-sudoku/source/browse/trunk/Sudoku/src/neural/network/sudoku/Board.java?spec=svn4&r=4)

But when i run it as Java Application it gives error "Selection Does not contain main type" As i am new n java.
any kind of help will b appreciated :-)

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there that demonstrate how to compile and run java files. You should search the web.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   If it is 'short' enough (e.g. significantly less than 418 lines), edit it directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the Board constructor from your main class to display the frame

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  Board board = new Board();
}
```

Comment: I worked my level best to run this code...
now this code is running but didn't give desired output :(
can you  plz have a look at this code.